# can I use sonycybershot digital camera for videochatting

Tags: software-recommendation, camera

I have an HP laptop which have a built in web camera. It has low visual clarity. So I like to use my digital camera as web cam. Is it possible. If yes, how?
which software is suitable for that? camera have usb cable.

Comment: Patience, please. This question was asked only one hour ago, and thus hardly anyone has looked into it by now. Also: Don't add more and more comments to your question, as this only clutters the list - Edit your question and include only *necessary* information.

Answer (score 0):

If your camera has a webcam mode you should be able to use it as any other webcam. Just change the device in the options of whatever program you use. Of course you have to activate that mode on your camera first. If it doesn't have such a mode, you can't use it as webcam no matter what software or operating system you use.

Comment: no webcam mode in my camera,  can i use webcamstudio for this

Comment: no, as long as you have no means to get the video signal from your webcam into your laptop in realtime it wont do you any good. Most digital cameras show themselves as USB storage if you connect them. You can copy the videos you recorded before but there is no way to get the video signal.